# Не могу довести до конца JS click

Tags: javascript

При клике на `n`-ый `.team-j` надо добавит `.show` к `team-card-j` к тому же же `n`-ому элементу.

```js
function team() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("team-j");
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName("team-card-j");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {

      for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        b[j].classList.remove("show");
      }
    });
  }
}
team();
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="team-card-j show"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function team() {
  var a = document.getElementsByClassName("team-j");
  var b = document.getElementsByClassName("team-card-j");
  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    a[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
      for (var j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
        b[j].classList.remove("show");
        if(this == a[j])
           b[j].classList.add("show");
      }
      
     
    });
  }
}
team();
```

```css
.team-j {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
.team-card-j {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.team-card-j.show{
  border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
  <div class="team-j"></div>
</div>
<div>
  <div class="team-card-j show"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
  <div class="team-card-j"></div>
</div>
```